# How to apply printf(...) inspection hint to a custom function when using IntelliJ Reshaper in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resharper

IntelliJ Reshaper will offer fantastic inspection hints for the following:

```
printf("%s", 5); // have warning inspection hint.
```

Which will indicate that the format string does not match the type of its arguments. I love this.

Now I want to make a custom function have the same feature, how to implement it?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html#custom

Similar to the custom string formatting methods mentioned in the link above, I tried to use the following code in Visual C++, but it didn't work. It seems that it only has an effect on C#.

```
#include <string>

std::string format_v(const char* formatString, va_list args)
{
    std::string result;
    auto len = _vscprintf(formatString, args);
    if (len == -1)
        return result;
    result.resize(len);
    vsprintf_s(&result[0], result.size() + 1, formatString, args);
    return result;
}

[StringFormatMethod("formatString")]
std::string format(const char* formatString, ...)
{
    std::string result;
    if (!formatString)
        return result;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, formatString);
    result = format_v(formatString, args);
    va_end(args);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s", 5); // have warning inspection hint.
    std::string msg = format("%s", 122); // no inspection hint.
    return 0; 
}

build failed:

warning C4467: usage of ATL attributes is deprecated
error C2337: 'StringFormatMethod': attribute not found
```

I try to clarify this problem, and hope you can understand it. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example the `[[rscpp::format]]` attribute or a number of other supported attributes. See [RSCPP-15890](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-15890) for discussion and examples.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, unless they have implemented them in very recent versions, format warnings have never been supported by MSVC (Microsoft's C++ compiler).
GCC has had them (as an extension) for years, and so has Clang:

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))
void my_print_func(const char *const s, ...) {
    // ...
}
```

You could try to work around this by compiling your code with Clang/LLVM on Windows (`clang-cl` has achieved an extremely high degree of compatibility with MSVC's `cl`). After you are certain there are no errors in your strings, you may switch back to `cl.exe` or stick with using `clang-cl`.

In order to keep those GCC-specific attributes from breaking your code under MSVC, you may use a macro like the following one, which I've found in the Chromium codebase:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define PRINTF_FORMAT(format_param, dots_param) \
  __attribute__((format(printf, format_param, dots_param)))
#else
#define PRINTF_FORMAT(format_param, dots_param)
#endif
```

`PRINTF_FORMAT` will be ignored under MSVC, while it will trigger format warnings under GCC and Clang.

Bonus: C++20 includes `std::format`, which provides you a newer, type safe way to format strings, as previously implemented by the [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library. You may give a look to {fmt}, or consider switching to C++20 and use `std::format` (which MSVC has recently implemented and it is going to be released soon).